# Can I add examples of file contents in OpenAPI specifications?

Tags: xml, swagger-ui, openapi

My service provides upload of XML-files. The OpenApi specification does not specify a schema. I want to provide an example input. I try this:

```
/foo:
    post:      
      requestBody:
        content: 
          application/xml:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
              example:
                  externalValue: 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml'
```

However, swagger-ui produces the unhelpful:

```
<!-- XML example cannot be generated; root element name is undefined -->
```

Is it possible to specify an example from an external file?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what version of OpenAPI you're using.

### OpenAPI 3.1

`externalValue` can be any valid UR**I**. This includes relative references. See the [3.1 documentation](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.1.0.md#example-object).

### OpenAPI 3.0

`externalValue` must be a valid UR**L**. It cannot be a relative file path. See the [3.0 documentation](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#example-object).

Change your value to the hosted location of your xml file.

---

The swagger-ui error is telling you you're not using a named element. Try providing a name. (Note that that tool has bugs and does not correctly support all valid OpenAPI designs. For example, [this related bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4650).)

```
examples:
  exampleName:
    summary: A sample object
    externalValue: 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml'
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm in OpenAPI 3.0. However, even using an absolute URI (see updated question), the example is not included in Swagger-ui output.

Comment: I've added additional information on something you can try.